# Want to set cron job for wordpress (Backwpup plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, webserver, centos

This is my first contact with cron jobs, so I'm sorry if my question sounds dumb.

BackWPup is for making a back up automatically after some period of time, but its own cron job does not work correctly. It starts only when I sign into wp-admin. So I decided to use the server's cron jobs, but I don't know how to. It says:

> If you would use the cron job of your hoster you must point it to the
>   url: http://example.com/wp-cron.php

Also, I want to know how to remove a job.

Note: I have only ssh access, there is no hosting control panel. OS: CentOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should add the command

```
wget http://example.com/wp-cron.php >> /path/to/my/wp-cron.log 2>&1
```

to the crontab. Of course you can use any other CLI http-tool instead of `wget`, but it's the most simple I know and I think is sufficient here.

Call

```
crontab -e
```

then add a line like

```
0 * * * * wget http://example.com/wp-cron.php >> /path/to/my/wp-cron.log 2>&1
```

This will call this command every hour. For further information see [`man crontab`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/).